# Time limit the execution of user code (JRuby)

Tags: jruby

Is it possible to restrict the amount of time the user code runs in JRuby?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. The user provided ruby code is running inside my java application, So I need a way to run it only for a specific amount of time. It's needed because the user may write code that results in infinite loops- that should be avoided.

Comment: I don't known how to to this in Java, but in Ruby you can do that with Timeout library: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you're embedding the Ruby code, but you could easily have a background timer thread that evaluates

```
raise YourTimeLimitExceededException, 'no more time'
```

after a period of time. You'd also want to disable Thread.new and Thread.start (as well as java.lang.Thread.new) for the user code, or they could easily circumvent your timer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer, please? (I'm using JRuby-embed)

Comment: Have a background thread measure the time spent, and call `scriptingContainer.evalScriptlet("raise Timeout::Timeout")` from the timer thread. You could use java.util.concurrent futures to help with making sure that the timeout doesn't get raised if the script completes in time.